# find distinct count of another table for grouped ids in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a MySQL query in which I am grouping by a column in Table_A. Now I want to find count of distinct values of a column in Table_B by reference id of Table_A for each group of Table_A.

Tried in many ways, but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it like this:

```
select A_id, count(distinct someField)
from Table_B
group by A_id
```

If you want me to convert this query to be more resembling to your schema, then you will need to provide more information on how Table_A and Table_B are connected to one another, what's your goal, how you want to group the results, what do you want to count and whether you want to get a 0 when a Table_A record has no references in Table_B